# ZF2 Segment Route doesn't match parent's constraint when using children

Tags: regex, routes, zend-framework2, zend-route

I created the following routes:

```
'relatorios' => array(
    'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'       => '/relatorios/:tipo',
        'defaults'    => array(
            'controller' => 'Relatorios',
            'action'     => 'index',
            'tipo'       => 'normais',
        ),
        'constraints' => array('tipo' => '(normais|administrativos)$',
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes'  => array(
        'view' => array(
            'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'       => '/view/:id_relatorio',
                'defaults'    => array('action'       => 'view'),
                'constraints' => array('id_relatorio' => '[0-9]+'),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

This is supposed to match the following routes:
/relatorios/normais `//matches`
/relatorios/administrativos `//matches`
/relatorios/normais/view/1 `//doesn't match`
/relatorios/administrativos/view/1 `//doesn't match`

So basically the `:tipo` parameter must be either `normais` or `administrativos` and there is a child `/view/any_digits`.
When the parent route is called it matches, when the child view is called it doesn't match because of my `tipo` constraint. Why is that?

Comment: Remove the `$` on the constraint - that shouldn't be there. Not sure if that's the issue or not - what error do you get?

Comment: @TimFountain It worked, such an easy modification hahaha... please, answer that so I can mark as solved, thank you!
By the way, it was showing `The requested URL could not be matched by routing.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, the `$` on the constraint means 'end of the string' (which in this case is the URL path), so it shouldn't be there.